# How do I get my for loop to keep from duplicating my data?

Tags: python

I am new to python and I'm trying to get my script to read the right areas in a file. The script is supposed to read through the file and then create a config file with the information csv file that is uploaded with all the parameters to add, update or delete. Right now I just noticed that my loop isn't going through the file, it's only reading the last line. So I moved the called function around and I noticed that it looped through and printed out the data more than once. When it's only supposed to print it out once. Here is what a normal config file is supposed to look like when the script runs right:

```
define hostgroup {
     hostgroup_name                 ISD-CR-All_Servers_group      
     notes                                                        
     alias                                                        
     action_url                                                   
     notes_url                                                    
     members                                                      
     hostgroup_members                                            
}
```

Here is what it looks like with the way my script is written:

```
define hostgroup {
     hostgroup_name                 ISD-CR-All_Servers            
     notes                                                        
     alias                                                        
     action_url                                                   
     notes_url                                                    
     members                                                      
     hostgroup_members                                            
}

# Configuration file /etc/nagios/objects/solution1/ISD-CR-All_Servers.cfg
# Edited by PyNag on Wed Jan  7 22:47:21 2015

define hostgroup {
     hostgroup_name                 ISD-CR-All_Servers            
     notes                                                        
     alias                                                        
     action_url                                                   
     notes_url                                                    
     members                                                      
     hostgroup_members                                            
}

# Configuration file /etc/nagios/objects/solution1/ISD-CR-All_Servers.cfg
# Edited by PyNag on Wed Jan  7 22:47:22 2015

define hostgroup {
     hostgroup_name                 ISD-CR-All_Servers            
     notes                                                        
     alias                                                        
     action_url                                                   
     notes_url                                                    
     members                                                      
     hostgroup_members                                            
}
```

The file that is uploaded looks like this:

```
Add Host Group  ISD-CR  ISD-CR-All_Servers      

Add Host Group  ISD-CR  ISD-CR-All_Servers      
Update  Service ISD-CR      ISD-CR-All_Servers  ISD-CR-Linux_Server
Update  Service ISD-CR      ISD-CR-Db_Servers   ISD-CR-Mango_db

Delete  Service Group   ISD-CR          
Delete  Service Group   ISD-CR          
Delete  Host Group  ISD-CR  ISD-CR-All_Servers      
Add Service Group   ISD-CR  ISD-CR-All_Servers_group        
Update  Service ISD-CR      ISD-CR-Web_Servers  ISD-CR-Web_link
```

And here is my script:

```
from pynag import Model
from pynag.Parsers import config
from subprocess import *
import subprocess
import sys

def addHostGroup():


            # Add hostgroup object
            hg = Model.Hostgroup()

            hg.set_filename('/etc/nagios/objects/solution1/{0}.cfg'.format(hostgroup_name))

            # Adding all attributes to allow any to be added if needed
            hg.hostgroup_name = row[3]
            hg.alias = row[4]
            hg.members = row[5]
            hg.hostgroup_members = row[6]
            hg.notes =  row[7]
            hg.notes_url = row[8]
            hg.action_url = row[9]

            # Save
            hg.save()

            print "hostgroup added"

def existHostGroup():        

        hostgroup = os.system('pynag list where hostgroup_name=hostgroup_name')
        if not hostgroup:
            logging.error("Hostgroup %s not found." % hostgroup_name)
            print 'adding objects'
            addHostGroup()


        print hostgroup
try:
        current_file = csv.reader(open(input_file, "rb"), delimiter='\t')
    except:  
        logging.error('No such file or directory. Please try again')
    else:
        for line in current_file:        
            for row in current_file:                        
                hostgroup_name = row[3]               
                if solution_id != row[2]:
                        logging.error('Solution ID is invalid. Please check the number and try again') 
                elif addAction() != row[0] and updateAction() != row[0] and deleteAction() != row[0]:
                        logging.error("Undefined action")
                elif object_hostgroup() != row[1] and object_service() != row[1] and object_servicegroup() != row[1]:
                        logging.error("Undefined object") 
                     # add in options checking if object(alias,hostgroup_name, etc) exists
                     # select add, modify or delete                                                                                                                    
                else:  
                    print row 
                    existHostGroup()


    finally:
        print "all error checks done!"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the lines:

```
    for line in current_file:        
        for row in current_file:
```

To the Python interpreter, these both mean the same thing: read lines from the file. Python doesn't know anything about the variables, it's just reading all of the lines once per line. Instead, just remove the first of these lines:

```
    for row in line:
```